# What is the context passed by android in the onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

When I instantiate a BroadcastReceiver and when onReceive() is get called by android framework, what is the context passed to the onReceive() method?
Is that an activity context? of an application context?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It Is An Application Context.

```
public abstract void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
```

Comment: It may be an Application Context, but it is a restricted version of that Context. In the Android source code for `Context` this is referred to as `ReceiverRestrictedContext` and this Context doesn't allow certain operations like `registerReceiver()` and `bindService()`. If you really need an Application Context in `onReceive()` then you need to call `context.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 Context of which application? The application receiving the broadcast or the application sending the broadcast?

Answer (score 6):

Historically, it's an instance of `ReceiverRestrictedContext`, but this class is gone in recent Android versions (don't know which API level exactly, but it's not present in API 26 sources), so now, it should be your Application Context.

`ReceiverRestrictedContext` prevented to register a `BroadcastReceiver` from a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Since an instance of `ReceiverRestrictedContext` is created each time your `BroadcastReceiver` is instantiated, you have to beware of not passing it to a component having a lifecycle longer than yours (very short lived) `BroadcastReceiver`, or you would create memory leaks on these older (not so much as of now) Android versions which have this `ReceiverRestrictedContext`.

You can safely call `getApplicationContext()` and pass its result to a longer lived component though.

Note that the fact `ReceiverRestrictedContext` is gone from recent Android versions doesn't mean you can make a "BroadcastReceiverCeption"!

Answer (score 0):

It's the context in which the receiver is running. For example, if the broadcast message is from UsbManager, the context is the context of UsbManager.
More info: [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent))

Comment: This does not make sense. The context is more likely to be the context on which the receiver was registered, rather than the context of who *sent* the broadcast. Your example with UsbManager suggests a broadcast from a (system) component outside of your app; it would not make sense if your receiver was invoked with the context of another app...